# How to update the slug and change the Wordpress permalink?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, taxonomy, permalinks, slug

I have a problem with permalinks. In my site, I register the custom post type name '*product*' and taxonomy '*type*' . In taxonomy '*type*', I added terms like :

- food

  - food A
  - food B
- drink

  - drink A
  - drink B

With each product, I added one term, i.e. product1 in food A , etc.

The permalink is like this:

```
Product : http://abc.com/product/product1
Taxonomy : http://abc.com/type/food
           http://abc.com/type/food-a
```

But I want the permalink changed to this:

```
Product : http://abc.com/product-type/food/food-a/product1
Taxonomy : http://abc.com/product-type/food
           http://abc.com/product-type/food/food-a
```

I tried to configure .htaccess file but I can't change anything. I found in Wordpress Answers a solution is to change the "*Rewrite*" in  **register_taxonomy** function but I can't change anything again.

```
'rewrite'=>array('hierarchical' => true,'slug' => 'product-type')
```

I already added products, and now I can't find any way to change the permalinks. I hope someone can help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: "slugre"? Am I the only one who can't parse that word?

Comment: For changing the slug name,you can go to page/post edit section in admin and below the post/page title,click on the "edit" button and change the slug and click "ok" button to save it.I think this might help you a little.